# Applying a theme to jqGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I am trying to apply a theme to jqGrid. I have searched for information but I cannot found a site where it explains step by step. So could someone tell me how to do this?
My project is being developed in asp.net mvc4, jquery and jqGrid.

**First attempt:**

I have downloaded redmond theme and I have put it under \Content folder in my mvc4 asp.net project. redmond folder contains one folder for images and in the root, three css files like below:

```
\Content
     \redmond
         \images
         jquery-ui.css
         jquery-ui.min.css
         jquery.ui.theme.css
```

so in order to use theme in my master page, in head tag I do:

```
<head>

   ...

        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/redmond/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" />

        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" />

        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/redmond/jquery.ui.theme.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" />

   ...
</head>
```

and in the body of the master page as well i do:

```
(...)

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")


        @Content.Script("jquery-1.10.2.min.js", Url)
        @Content.Script("jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js", Url)
        @Content.Script("jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js", Url)
        @Content.Script("jquery.dd.js", Url)
        @Content.Script("grid.locale-en.js", Url)        
        @Content.Script("jquery.jqGrid.min.js", Url)

        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>

(...)
```

Note that i refer to @Content, which is an cshtml file in my \app_code folder and its content is:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc;
@helper Script(string scriptName, UrlHelper url)
{
    <script src="@url.Content(string.Format("~/Scripts/{0}", scriptName))" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

now the theme is applied to my jqGrid but after the theme is applied all my page which contains it and even the master page get as blocked (disabled, grayed) and at the bottom of the page below is shown (a warning window saying: please, select a row):

http://snag.gy/AgUvM.jpg

what's happenning? Any ideas?

**Solution:**

I was using a dropdown scripting file jquery-dd.js but I forgot to add the css style for it in the head tag in my master page(also i forgot to include the css file for jqGrid):

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/dd.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/ui.jqGrid.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the useful link for build your jquery theme. [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/). What you need to do is pick your desired theme and download the files from link at the bottom of page. Use it in your asp.net-mvc application. Hope this helps..

Comment: Ok, download the compressed file (Themes links at the bottom) and then put the desired theme folder under my \Content folder right? I have seen that there are only a images folder with lot of gifs, pngs and some css files in the root. I guess jquery-ui-xxx.js is used to load them right (in my Script folder)?

Comment: Yes you are correct. I hope you picked your theme. What you need to do is call the css file inside of your theme and add latest jquery and jquery-ui js files. You will get it.

Comment: i have done it, theme is applied now, but when applied all the page, even master page gets blocked (disabled) and a window appears at the bottom of the page saying: "please, select a row". See my updated post please.

Comment: As you answered first, i have accepted yours as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you have picked a theme (I'm assuming a jQuery UI theme) you can save it in an accessible folder (/Content/Themes/ etc).

After that it should be as easy as adding the theme to your view or layout.

Ex:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

(in this example I picked the 'Redmond' theme, and had a custom version of jquery ui 1.10.3)

Then just ensure your view, when you load it, actually can access the css file you have linked.

Comment: i have done it, theme is applied now, but when applied all the page, even master page gets blocked (disabled) and a window appears at the bottom of the page saying: "please, select a row". See my updated post please.